# getting video link source full screen video player android java

Tags: java, android, webview, webchromeclient

I have webview android application and I play embed videos inside it. I can play This videos is fullscreen. I want to get video source link from it. I think that if i play this videos fullscreen. I can get source link of videos. Is it possible ?

So I am sure it is possible but i dont know how. because all links passes inside webchromeclient, WebViewClient, videoview or other class that i dont know. do you have any ideas ?

```html
        webView2.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override

            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
            }

}
```

Comment: it all depends on where you play videos from. Some services don't give direct links.

Comment: i dont want to write bot for all of each. android must learn streaming link before play. because when we play fullscreen android uses own player. if it see, we should see.

Comment: I don't think that it uses something special for full-screen.